# SQL oracle next value

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get next value (nextname1) for each name1 and id? `SQL Oracle.`
Im try use analytic function `LEAD` and `LAST_VALUE` but not working:

```
LEAD(name1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) as nextname1
```

returns:

```
id name1 (nextname1)
1  AA  (AA)
2  AA  (AA)
3  AA  (MB)
4  MB  (MB)
5  MB  (BB)
6  BB  (BB)
7  BB  (ZZ)
8  ZZ  (null)
```

I want:

```
id name1 (nextname1)
1  AA  (MB)
2  AA  (MB)
3  AA  (MB)
4  MB  (BB)
5  MB  (BB)
6  BB  (ZZ)
7  BB  (ZZ)
8  ZZ  (null)
```

note: I have a table with millions of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with two steps:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2               SELECT 1 id, 'AA' name FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 2 id, 'AA' name FROM DUAL
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 3 id, 'AA' name FROM DUAL
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 4 id, 'MB' name FROM DUAL
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 5 id, 'MB' name FROM DUAL
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 6 id, 'BB' name FROM DUAL
  8     UNION ALL SELECT 7 id, 'BB' name FROM DUAL
  9     UNION ALL SELECT 8 id, 'ZZ' name FROM DUAL
 10  )
 11  SELECT v.*, max(first_step) OVER (PARTITION BY name) nextname
 12    FROM (SELECT data.*,
 13                 nullif(lead(name) OVER (ORDER BY id), name) first_step
 14            FROM data) v
 15   ORDER BY id;

        ID NA FI NE
---------- -- -- --
         1 AA    MB
         2 AA    MB
         3 AA MB MB
         4 MB    BB
         5 MB BB BB
         6 BB    ZZ
         7 BB ZZ ZZ
         8 ZZ
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a table with millions of records, so it's not a good solution :(

Comment: @AdamKozlowski: why is the number of rows a reason not to use this solution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, it works. I do not understand what is "WITH DATA AS (" I thought that you need to do UNION ALL ... for all data. Now all clear, thx :-)

Answer (score 1):

No need for analytical functions. Use a nested select:

```
with data as (
  select 1 id, 'AA' name1 from dual union all
  select 2 id, 'AA' name1 from dual union all
  select 3 id, 'AA' name1 from dual union all
  select 4 id, 'MB' name1 from dual union all
  select 5 id, 'MB' name1 from dual union all
  select 6 id, 'BB' name1 from dual union all
  select 7 id, 'BB' name1 from dual union all
  select 8 id, 'ZZ' name1 from dual
)
select d1.id, d1.name1, (
  select name1 
  from data d2
  where d2.id > d1.id
  and d2.name1 <> d1.name1
  and rownum = 1
) nextname1
from data d1
```

Comment: No need for nested selects, use analytics :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: Agreed. Specifically since that `rownum` filter only works with the CTE which is implicitly ordered. With the real life table, I'd have to double-nest the select

Comment: and this double nesting wouldn't work since you can't push a variable two level deep !

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: I know. I was thinking about another nested select: `not exists(select 1 from data d3 where...)`. But then I got too lazy to write it down ;-)